# Spring Boot properties: Load Balanced datasource

Tags: oracle, properties, spring-boot, datasource

I have following definition of datasource:

```
spring.datasource.url      = jdbc:oracle:thin:@ (DESCRIPTION = \
(ADDRESS_LIST = \
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SOME-DB-SERVER)(PORT = 1521)) \
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SOME-DB-OTHER)(PORT = 1521)) \
  (LOAD_BALANCE = yes) \
) \
(CONNECT_DATA = \
  (SERVICE_NAME = My.service) \
) \
)
```

And it seems that this does not work. When the first server does not answer, the second one does not take its function and causes error on startup.

Is there a way to define such datasource?

Answer (score 1):

as far as this doc puts it:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/e10788/rac.htm#CHDHCGGG

you seem to have an error in this statement:
LOAD_BALANCE = yes

seems it should be:
LOAD_BALANCE = on

below full sample connection string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin@(DESCRIPTION=
   (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=racnode1) (PORT=1521))
   (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=racnode2) (PORT=1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

add LOAD_BALANCE=on instead of yes, I have used this many time and works for me.